# select div inside of table cell jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to select the deeply buried div with class "srch-maintop" with the context of the topmost div "srch-sb-results". How do I select the srch-maintop div using jquery?

Am I even close here?

```
$('.srch-sb-results').next('table').find('td#MainLeftCell div.srch-maintop').delete();
```

That didn't even touch it..

```
<div class="srch-sb-results"> stuff here </div>
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td colspan='3'>
             <div style="border:1px solid silver"></div>
           </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td class="srch-leftcell">stuff</td>

            <td class="srch-mainleftcell">
               <div>stuff</div>
               <div class="srch-maintop"></div>
               <div class="srch-maintop2"></div>
            </td>

            <td class="srch-rightcell">stuff</td>
         </tr>

    <table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**remove()**](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) instead:

```
$('.srch-sb-results').next('table').find('td#MainLeftCell div.srch-maintop').remove();
```

And there is no `class` or `id` named `MainLeftCell`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you write `#MainLeftCell` as **ID**, but you have to write it as **class** `.MainLeftCell`. And yes ... you can use `.remove()` instead `.delete()`

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you were close ;)

`$('.srch-sb-results').next('table').find('td.srch-mainleftcell div.srch-maintop').delete();`

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other element with the given class you can just use it by itself:

```
$('.srch-maintop').remove();
```

Or to find a more specific one in the table next to the div with class 'srch-sb-results':

```
$('.srch-sb-results').next('table').find('.srch-maintop').remove();
```